# Magento 2 How to disable maintenance mode when deployment mode is production

Tags: magento2, maintenance

I am using **production mode** in magento, but in **frontend** it is showing **Maintenance mode** is enabled.

I am new in magento. Please guide me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clean your caches and flush your site. Run this code :  php bin/magento cache:flush

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in your root directory their is `var` folder, under that find `maintenance.log` and delete it.

Second method is run below mentioned command in your terminal:

```
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

In the end, run this command:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: ok I am trying this.

Comment: It's working. thanks.

Comment: my pleasure. :)

Answer (score 0):

Run from command line (using correct user and php):

```
sudo -u www-data php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```